# Add button in customer edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I want add a new button in customer edit page.

Here:
[image: Add button]

Between Reset and Create Order.

I try override "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit" but when go to the customer edit page return this error:

[image: error]

This is my config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <company_unblock>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <depends>
                <!-- no dependencies -->
            </depends>
        </company_unblock>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models />
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>                   
                    <customer_edit>Company_Unblock_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit</customer_edit>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </block>
        <resources />
        <extraconfig />
        <helpers>
            <unblock>
                <class>Company_Unblock_Helper</class>
            </unblock>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <company_unblock>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Unblock</module>
                    <frontName>unblock</frontName>
                </args>
            </company_unblock>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

In the Block override only modify function construct:

```
class Company_Unblock_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_controller = 'customer';

        if ($this->getCustomerId() && 
            Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/create')) {
            $this->_addButton('order', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Create Order'),
                'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getCreateOrderUrl() . '\')',
                'class' => 'add',
            ), 0);

        }

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Save Customer'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Delete Customer'));

        if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->isReadonly()) {
            $this->_removeButton('save');
            $this->_removeButton('reset');
        }

        if (!Mage::registry('current_customer')->isDeleteable()) {
            $this->_removeButton('delete');
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add a custom button without override? – str_lml

You can add buttons via event/observer ...

```
<adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    <observers>
        <add_some_buttons>
            <class>[module]/observer</class>
            <method>addButton</method>
        </add_some_buttons>
    </observers>
</adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
```

Observer:

```
public function addButton(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($observer->getBlock()->getType() != 'adminhtml/customer_edit') {
        return;
    }

    $data = array(
        'label'     => '...',
        'onclick'   => '...',
    );
    $observer->getBlock()->addButton('your_button', $data);
}
```

For the correct position, see `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container::addButton()`

```
public function addButton($id, $data, $level = 0, $sortOrder = 0, $area = 'header')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.xml`  below code is there if its not used then remove it

```
<helpers>
    <unblock>
    <class>Company_Unblock_Helper</class>
    </unblock>
</helpers>
```

or create  a helper classs

in `app/code/[codePool]/Company/Unblock/Helper` and put below code in `Data.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Unblock_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Comment: The helper class will be needed anyway for module's translations

Comment: @simonthesorcerer , that's depends on his requirement , if he wants to translate text then yes its needed

Comment: I remove the Helper code in config.xml and in my construct i have $this->_addBUtton(".....") but don't show the new button is like don't override the function.

Comment: Can I add a custom button without override?

Comment: @str_lml is `order` is your button ???

Comment: order is the button added by Magento i need add other button. I try to change this but nothing happened